# Onclick function based on element id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, getelementbyid

I'm working on a site with a visualization of inheritance relation.

I try to link each nodebox with specific URLs. The html of Element looks like this:

```
<g class="node" id="RootNode" transform="translate(0,453.125)">
```

I used

```
$('#RootNode').click(function(){//do something}
```

and also

```
document.getElementById("RootNode").onclick(){//do something}
```

Neither of them can find the element, nor setup the onclick function.

Have I misunderstood anything? Any information will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Neither of those syntaxes are correct.

Comment: Does the #RootNode element already exist when the handler is bound?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Make sure your code is in [DOM Ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) as pointed by [rocket-hazmat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/206403/rocket-hazmat)

[.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

```
$('#RootNode').click(function(){
  //do something
});
```

---

```
document.getElementById("RootNode").onclick = function(){//do something}
```

---

[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Use [event Delegation/](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
$(document).on("click", "#RootNode", function(){
   //do something
});
```

---

Try

Wrap Code in Dom Ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#RootNode').click(function(){
     //do something
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry about that it was a typo. With .click it's still not working.

Comment: @FelixWang: Is your code inside a `$(function(){})` (or `$(document).ready(function(){})`)?

Comment: @RocketHazmat added your helpful comment to answer .

Comment: @RocketHazmat I used $(document).on("click", "#RootNode", function(){
    //do something 
}); and it works for my case. Why the .click does not work?

Comment: @FelixWang: Because you are trying to bind it *before* it exists in the DOM.  You need to wait until the DOM is ready.  `$(document).on("click", "#RootNode"` actually binds the event to the `document` and just checks to see if it matches the selector (it's called "event delegation" and is used to bind events to elements that will be added to your page in the future).

Comment: @FelixWang you must have added `#RootNode` element after DOM is ready.  Read ---> https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/
As your elemet `#RootNode` was not present at DOM ready so click  handler was not attached to it .So we used `.on()` to register handler to `document`

Answer (score 8):

you can try these:

```
document.getElementById("RootNode").onclick = function(){/*do something*/};
```

or

```
$('#RootNode').click(function(){/*do something*/});
```

or

```
$(document).on("click", "#RootNode", function(){/*do something*/});
```

There is a point for the first two method which is, it matters where in your page DOM, you should put them, the whole DOM should be loaded, to be able to find the, which is usually it gets solved if you wrap them in a `window.onload` or `DOMReady` event, like:

```
//in Vanilla JavaScript
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
     document.getElementById("RootNode").onclick = function(){/*do something*/};
});
//for jQuery
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#RootNode').click(function(){/*do something*/});
});
```

Comment: Give me some minutes, I cannot accept this so soon. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#click").click(function(){
    console.log("button clicked");
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="click">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
document.getElementById("RootNode").onclick = function() {
  /* do something */
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.