# Javascript - Show alert when specific radio button is checked on ID

Tags: javascript, alert

I need to show a alert when someone clicks on a radio button with a specific ID.

This is the radio button:

```
<input name="shipping_method" type="radio" class="validate-one-required-by-name" value="kerst_shipping_standard" id="s_method_kerst_shipping_standard">
```

And when someone clicks that radio button it needs to show a alert.

Comment: That's not giving me the right answer since the inputs are generated by code, so I can't add the onclick="alert('test');" in the input tag, I need to do it by javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
document.getElementById('s_method_kerst_shipping_standard').addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert('ok');
});
```

I am assuming ID is unique in the document.

Answer (score 1):

Try next code:

```js
document.getElementById("s_method_kerst_shipping_standard").addEventListener('click',function(){
    alert('clicked');
})
```

```html
<input name="shipping_method" type="radio" class="validate-one-required-by-name" value="kerst_shipping_standard" id="s_method_kerst_shipping_standard">
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, this works also!

Answer (score 1):

Quick example :

```
document.getElementById("s_method_kerst_shipping_standard").onclick = function(){
  alert('Your alert')
}
```

Link to similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21835012/onclick-function-based-on-element-id)

Answer (score 1):

> This could easily be done by selecting your `button` using the document
>   method
>   **[getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)**
>   and binding a function with your
>   **[alert](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert)**
>   inside to its
>   **[onclick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/onclick)**.

like i did below:

```js
document.getElementById('s_method_kerst_shipping_standard').onclick = function(){
  alert("Alert!");
};
```

```html
<input name="shipping_method" type="radio" class="validate-one-required-by-name" value="kerst_shipping_standard" id="s_method_kerst_shipping_standard">
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, this works also!

Answer (score 1):

```
    radioBtn = document.querySelector("#s_method_kerst_shipping_standard");
  console.log(radioBtn);

  radioBtn.addEventListener("click",function(e){
      alert("test")

  }
)
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, this works also!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, it is better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers tend to be less useful in the long run. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for some more info.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function inputSelect(value)
      {
       if(document.getElementById("s_method_kerst_shipping_standard").checked===true)
       {
           alert("You Clicked");
       }
      }
```

```html
<input name="shipping_method" type="radio" class="validate-one-required-by-name" value="kerst_shipping_standard" id="s_method_kerst_shipping_standard" onclick="inputSelect(this.value)">
```

You have to set an onclick listener. You can check whether it is selected or not in javascript as follow